# Stop Windows 10 Quick Access Collapse

Tags: windows-10

In Windows 10, the "Quick Access" always seems to collapse or dissapear when I am using it - it is no longer "quick" as it always requires me to scroll up to it, and click on the little triangle to expand it. Is there a way to make Quick Access always open, and always visible so that I can use it quickly?

In addition to stopping, I'd prefer it not jump to the folder I am looking at. Possible to do this?

This question is the same as an [unanswered question at the microsoft forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-desktop/quick-access-folder-always-collapses/13019e5b-cc19-4867-9800-149d37c80b9f).

Comment: Downvote with no comment? Boooooooo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on Quick Access and choose options and then hit the "view" tab. Scroll all the way down on "Advanced Settings" then under "Navigation pane" uncheck "Expand to open folder."

Once that's unchecked, it should prevent collapsing the folder locations.

[image: Folder Options]

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't work for me - it was already unticked when I went to the view tab. This answer had 3 upvotes when I got here, so it must have worked for 3 other people, very weird.

Answer (score 0):

If found an answer [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-desktop/quick-access-folder-always-collapses/13019e5b-cc19-4867-9800-149d37c80b9f) -

> Go into Options with right click on Quick Access and then untick Show recently and Show frequently options.So now it will only show the folders I want it to, and will therefore keep to its normal size.

Check if it solves your problem.